# Where can I find a list of all possible keys for tm-themes for syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

In the tmTheme file for my current text editor there are a number of options, including the ones in the code below. Is there a list somewhere that defines all possible tags that could be included in this list (eg. `background`, `inactiveSelection`, `findHighlight`, etc)?

```xml
<dict>

<key>background</key>
<string>#1a1a1a</string>

<key>caret</key>
<string>#B6ECF9AF</string>

<key>foreground</key>
<string>#ecf0f1</string>

<key>invisibles</key>
<string>#F3FFB51A</string>

<key>lineHighlight</key>
<string>#2a2a2a</string>

<key>selection</key>
<string>#e74c3c55</string>

<key>selectionForeground</key>
<string>#ffffff</string>

<key>findHighlight</key>
<string>#e74c3c</string>

<key>inactiveSelection</key>
<string>#e74c3c77</string>

<key>gutter</key>
<string>#2a2a2a</string>

<key>gutterForeground</key>
<string>#ffffff</string>

<key>guide</key>
<string>#222222</string>

<key>activeGuide</key>
<string>#ffffff</string>

</dict>
```

Another example with even more tags: [Other Theme](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Angular-io-Code)

If it's relevant, I'm using VSCode.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

tmLanguage scope names are based on convention, so there's no definitive list. The "Naming Conventions" section at the bottom of [this](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) TextMate Manual page is fairly comprehensive though.

You can also check what scopes are highlighted by VSCode's default themes, see for instance [`dark_plus.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.9.0/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/dark_plus.json) and [`dark_vs.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.9.0/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/dark_vs.json) (which the former is based on / includes).

Finally, as of VSCode 1.9.0, there is a builtin command to inspect tmLanguage scopes (`Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`). It will give you a lot of information over how the token at the cursor location is scoped / highlighted:

[image]

There is also a [Scope Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.scope-info) extension which does a very similar thing, but on hover (which I personally prefer usability-wise). However, it only lists the scope names, not including any of the additional info that VSCode's built-in inspector has.

Comment: The most important part of what I was trying to find out here is just barely peeking out from behind the hover info: That "scope" can be an array of scope names. I was having trouble figuring out how to specify a hierarchy like this: `"scope": ["text.html.markdown", "invalid.illegal.expected-dictionary-separator.json"]`