# Set color of quotes in Visual Studio Code customized theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm using vscode a customized theme of my own, which I based on another theme. Currently text like this is displayed in white:

> """ some Python comment """

I would like to change the color but cannot find the right attribute to change. I tried adding this in the `*.tmTheme` file but it doesn't change anything:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Quotes</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>markup.quote</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#F77669</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Could you please help?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct tmLanguage scope name is **`string.quoted.docstring.multi.python`**.

It's easy to find by using the `Developer: Inspect TM scopes` command:

[image]

I wrote about tmLanguage scope names in a bit more detail in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117021/2631715).

The following works in a `.tmTheme` for me (compared to your example, I only changed the `<string>` after the `scope` key):

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Quotes</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>string.quoted.docstring.multi.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#F77669</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: How would this be changed in the user settings file?

Comment: @JohnSardinha You can use the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46049518/2631715.