# How to change colors of syntax highlights in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working with React, and Language Mode of VS Code set to Javascript React.

Code in Text Editor looks like this:

[image]

I want "Text", which refers to normal text in React, to be of different color. But, I can't find the suitable prop in `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting to tweak. What is the right prop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a list of all possible keys for tm-themes for syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116486/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-possible-keys-for-tm-themes-for-syntax-highlighti)

Comment: @Gama11 Did not find the answer there.

Comment: The `Inspect TM Scopes` scopes command should give you a list of scopes.