# How to color certain token from custom language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, color-scheme

I create custom langauge `abc`, from tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide, hence my files contains:

package.json:

```
{
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": "abc",
                "extensions": [".abc"]
            }
        ],
        "grammars": [
            {
                "language": "abc",
                "scopeName": "source.abc",
                "path": "./syntaxes/abc.tmGrammar.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

abc.tmGrammar.json:

```
{
    "scopeName": "source.abc",
    "patterns": [{ "include": "#expression" }],
    "repository": {
        "expression": {
            "patterns": [{ "include": "#letter" }, { "include": "#paren-expression" }]
        },
        "letter": {
            "match": "a|b|c",
            "name": "keyword.letter"
        },
        "paren-expression": {
            "begin": "\\(",
            "end": "\\)",
            "beginCaptures": {
                "0": { "name": "punctuation.paren.open" }
            },
            "endCaptures": {
                "0": { "name": "punctuation.paren.close" }
            },
            "name": "expression.group",
            "patterns": [{ "include": "#expression" }]
        }
    }
}
```

And this works, because when I open VSC I can see and can pick `abc` language. Now how to color `expression.group` token to #ff0000? Where define color for it? In `package.json` in `colors` contribution point?

Comment: Colors are provided by themes: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes. Usually you'd try to use common existing scope names that themes already target. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116486/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-possible-keys-for-tm-themes-for-syntax-highlighti

Comment: @Gama11 so I must create my custom theme based on existing one, and there set colors for my language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set your own theme styling, or set color in user setting.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66729

you can see the scope in command `developer inspect editor tokens and scopes`

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        // JavaScript
        {
            "scope": "source.js keyword",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000"
            }
        },
        // TypeScript
        {
            "scope": "source.ts keyword",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#0000ff"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: For others: I left that project, and can't verify answer.. Someone in comment for question post mention the same solution so probably it's correct. I don't want leave unanswered question.