# How to color certain characters with TextMate rules, for syntax highlighting in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, textmate

In VS Code, how can I set the color for the curly bracket characters `{`and `}` in `.ts` files?

In my `settings.json`, I currently have this as a starting point:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "entity.name.class, entity.name.type", 
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#cc0000",
                "fontStyle": "italic",
             }
        }],
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        "punctuation.definition.block.ts"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#ff0000"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Look at a few answers on SO about using the command "Inspect TM Scopes" to find out how this answer arrived at the "punctuation.definition.block.ts" scope.  Such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116486/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-possible-keys-for-tm-themes-for-syntax-highlighti/42117021#42117021