# How to change color of parentheses in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I set parentheses color as light-grey, to make  less visible?

So the expression

```
p(items.fold(0) { acc, i -> acc + i })
```

Will be visible as if there were no parentheses

```
p items.fold 0  { acc, i -> acc + i }
```

Comment: Always interesting to see creative freedom developers take for their coding preferences. This is a duplicate question, although, uniquely :) you can change it using the scope inspector to find the name of the token and targeting the token in your settings. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42116486 although many questions on here like it.

Comment: Oh and the setting you need is `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` you would just need to set it the same color as your background

Comment: what programming language is this?